# Calendar.set not changing Calendar variables

Tags: java, java.util.calendar

I've been working on a program for my Computer Programming class and I'm having a little trouble. Truthfully, I'm on the verge of insanity...

Its a calendar program and the part I'm having trouble with is the Calendar object in java. Here is my code for one of methods:

```
public static void calendarGet(){
  String md = getInput("What date would you like to look at?(mm/dd)"); 
  int slash = md.indexOf('/');
  MDFromDate(md);

  cal.set(cal.MONTH, MONTH - 1); 
  cal.set(cal.DATE, DAY); 

  TARGET_DAY = DAY;
  MAX_DAY = cal.getActualMaximum(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  WEEKS_IN_MONTH = MAX_DAY / 7;

  System.out.println(cal.MONTH + 1);
  System.out.println(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  System.out.println(cal.getTime());

  drawMonth(cal.MONTH);

}
```

And the output for this is:

```
What date would you like to look at?(mm/dd)12/12
3
5
Wed Dec 12 22:47:32 PST 2018
```

As you can see, if I use getTime(); it returns the right month and day but cal.MONTH and cal.DAY_OF_MONTH do not.

Also, when I use the debugger and look in cal, none of the variables had changed.

I'm incredibly confused, I would appreciate some help! :D

EDIT:

```
public static String getInput(String prompt){
     System.out.print(prompt);
     Scanner inScan = new Scanner(System.in);
     return inScan.nextLine();
}

public static void MDFromDate(String md){
     Scanner getMD = new Scanner(md).useDelimiter("/");
     MONTH = getMD.nextInt();
     DAY = getMD.nextInt();

}
```

Comment: Any reason why you're still using `Calendar` and not `java.Time` APIs instead?

Comment: *"I'm incredibly confused"* - You're not the only one - how is `MONTH` and `DAY` obtained?

Comment: My teacher felt strongly about us using it; I was confused as well.

Comment: *"My teacher felt strongly about us using it"* Your teachers ... out of touch :/

Comment: Don't post code in the comments, update you question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates what you are doing and the issues you are having - yes, this might require you to start a new project

Comment: Sorry this was my first post on the site.

So I might have to restart using java.Time?

Comment: If your teacher wants you using `Calendar`, use `Calendar`, let's get the assignment done first, then we can talk about best practices

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused, what do you recommend me doing? Thank you for your time, by the way.

Comment: I recommend you start by following what you teach has asked you to do - if they want you to use `Calendar`, then that's what you should use. But if you need us to help you, then you need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

So...

```
System.out.println(cal.MONTH + 1);
System.out.println(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

is printing the constant values assigned to `Calendar.MONTH` and `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`, this are not the values contained within the `Calendar` instance, they are simply values you can use to set/get values of the `Calendar`

So, if instead we use `Calendar#get`, for example...

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

int month = 12;
int day = 12;

cal.set(cal.MONTH, month - 1);
cal.set(cal.DATE, day);

System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

It will print...

```
11
12
```

But wait, why `11`, because the months are zero indexed (ie January is `0`)

Part of the confusion is down to the fact that you're not using the [standard coding conventions for the Java Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html), which states variable names which all all uppercase (`MONTH`/`DAY`) are constants, which they aren't in your code

And, yes, as I'm sure some is bound to point out, you shouldn't be using `Calendar` but instead the newer `java.time` API, but if your teacher wants you to use it, who are we to contradict them :/

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

In [a very well-explained answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49400535/5772882) MadProgrammer asks:

> And, yes, as I'm sure some is bound to point out, you shouldn't be
>   using `Calendar` but instead the newer `java.time` API, but if your
>   teacher wants you to use it, who are we to contradict them :/

I am taking the chance. If only for other readers that are not under the same restrictions. Teachers are different. When I was teaching, I certainly appreciated whenever students found a different solution from what I had imagined. You know your teacher better, so I hope you know what is right in your situation, I certainly don’t.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter monthDayFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d");

public static void calendarGet(){
      String md = getInput("What date would you like to look at?(mm/dd)");
      LocalDate date = MonthDay.parse(md, monthDayFormatter)
            .atYear(Year.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")).getValue());
      int targetDay = date.getDayOfMonth();
      int maxDay = date.lengthOfMonth();

      System.out.println(date.getMonth());
      System.out.println(date.getDayOfMonth());
}
```

When I entered `04/05`, this printed

```
APRIL
5
```

IMHO the code using `java.time` is clearer to read and what should be taught in schools.

Comment: Ill be sure to make use of this in the future, thank you very much!